# How to pause the C program?

Tags: c, pause, unistd.h

**Fixed**

```
system("read -r -p \"Press any key to continue...\" key")
```

I am now writing a command line tool and using C language, but I am wondering how to pause the program? (Not abort it, but can be re-continued) I was trying to make it like "Press Enter To Continue".

I am on Linux so I don't have  or what, I have , and I tried "pause()", but this function cannot realize "Press Enter To Continue", it cannot be re-continued.

Wonder if there is a function or what can help me to do that? If yes, please tell me, thanks!

***PS: These are my codes above, as you may see, I am using a function named "conti" to set a pause***

***PLUS: Ignore those "delay" functions, just doing tests.***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void delay500ms(void){
    unsigned char i,j,k;
    for(i=15;i>0;i--)
        for(j=202;j>0;j--)
            for(k=81;k>0;k--);
}

void delay1s(void){
    unsigned char h,i,j,k;
    for(h=5;h>0;h--)
        for(i=4;i>0;i--)
            for(j=116;j>0;j--)
                for(k=214;k>0;k--);
}

int pause(void);

int ldown (int ln)
{
    int k;
    for (k=0;k<ln;k++)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void conti ()
{
    printf("\n\nPress Enter To Continue...\n\n");
}

void cmd ()
{
    ldown(100);
    system("toilet -f mono12 -F metal S-MODE");
    ldown(4);
    printf("[1] Emergency Reboot\n");
    printf("[2] Clean All Progress\n");
    printf("[3] Change Into Pure Net\n");
    printf("[4] Change Into Normal Net\n");
    printf("[5] Edit This Script\n");
    printf("[6] Rebuild This Script\n");
    printf("[7] Delet This Script\n");
    printf("[8] Exit S-MODE\n\n");
    printf("Now Please Type Your Command [1~8]:\n");
    int cmdn;
    cmdn = 8;
    scanf("%d",&cmdn);
    ldown(4);
    switch (cmdn)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Checking Root Permision...\n\n");
            system("reboot");
            printf("\n\nShutting Down The System...\n\n");
            conti();
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Cleaning All Progress...\n\n");
            system("kill -9 -1");
            conti();
            break;
        case 3:
            system("pure");
            conti();
            break;
        case 4:
            system("unpure");
            conti();
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("Checking Root Permision...\n\n");
            system("sudo vim /bin/engage.c");
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("Checking Root Permision...\n\n");
            system("sudo gcc /bin/engage.c -o /bin/engage");
            printf("\n\nScript Rebuilt! Please Restart The Script\n");
            conti();
            break;
        case 7:
            printf("Checking Root Permision...\n\n");
            system("sudo rm /bin/engage");
            exit(0);
            break;
        case 8:
            printf("Exiting...");
            ldown(10);
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unknow Command :(\n\n");
            break;
    }
}

void main()
{
    do
    {
        cmd();
    } while (1==1);
}
```

Comment: clear the input buffer before calling `conti()`, and inside, just use a `getchar()`....that's all you'll need.

Comment: System("Pause"); should be the rigth way to go

Comment: Instead of telling us to "ignore" some piece of code, you should just remove it from the question. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  puts("Press any key to continue ... ");
  getchar();
}
```

If you really need to make it enter-accepted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  puts("Press enter to continue ... ");
  while(getchar()!=27);
}
```

27 is enter keycode.

Another C solution would be:

```
system("read -n1 -r -p \"Press any key to continue...\" key")
```

In c++ it would look like that:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  std::cout << "Press enter to continue ... " << std::endl;
  std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
  cin.get();
}
```

Comment: `If you really need to make it enter-accepted:`...emmm...why? Isn't it like you asked me that `Press any key to continue ... `?

Comment: @CoderBTS Okay, I've made an edit, now it should work.

Comment: But I tried both getch and getchar, both not working... you can try your self, use my source code. Wonder if the "break" influences it?

Comment: @CoderBTS No. It shouldn't be this.
Have you access to C++ <iostream>?

Comment: @Joel Nope exactly.

Comment: @CoderBTS Have you tried to `fflush(stdin)` before getchar()?

Comment: @CoderBTS I've updated my answer, check does 3rd method work for you

Comment: @Joel I removed the option -n1, now it works! Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to do this, what you can do is to add one of these into your `void conti()` function.

**getchar**

- returns the character read as an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error, `getchar();`

**In POSIX systems, you can use :**

```
#include <unistd.h>

pause ();
```

**In Windows,you can use kbhit().**

**kbhit() function**

- Is used to determine if a key has been pressed or not.
  To use kbhit() in C or C++ programs you have to include the header file "conio.h".

**Sample usage of kbhit():**

```
while (!kbhit())
    printf("Howdyy you haven't pressed a key.\n");
```

Comment: conio.h is library introduced in Borland C standard and there's a chance that OP has no access to this library.

Comment: but how can I re-continue from pause() ?

Answer (score -5):

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

  while(1){
    puts("Press command ... ");

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble of answering, but please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting, it seems that it would help you improving your answer. Also, I doubt the usefulness of an endless loop, which does output repeatedly, but ingores input. It does not really match the stated problem. I did not downvote, but what I described might have been on the mind of whoever did. Consider getting the badge for taking the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16222767)

Comment: @cpburnz I don't think that an answer being _wrong_ is a valid reason for deletion. After all, it _does_ "pause" the program like the OP requested (the fact it also makes the program useless is a different issue). This is exactly why downvotes exist...